# java spring type conversion StringToBigDecimal @NumberFormat("0.##")

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, type-conversion

I have a form with an input field bound to a Property of type BigDecimal.

```
@NumberFormat(pattern = "0.##")
    public BigDecimal getPurchasePrice() {
        return purchasePrice;
    }
```

My default locale is de_DE, and thus the decimalSeparator in use is comma ","

Now, I discovered that when entering values for the BigDecimal field, both of the following formats are processed correctly, e.g.:

12.45 (using dot)

12,45 (using comma)

both are converted and stored correctly.

I understand that 12,45 should be converted correctly, as I suppose that is what I use the annotation @NumberFormat for - to tell spring how I want my string-value to be converted to BigDecimal.

So why is 12.45 also converted correctly? I had a look into WebDataBinder and saw that it uses DefaultFormattingConversionService, which has a converter which seems to convert from String to BigDecimal, using NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory. This seems to be the Converter which actually takes my annotation into account and based on it evaluates it, right?

On the other hand I've found that there exists **org.springframework.binding.convert.converters.StringToBigDecimal** but I am not sure if it is used in my case.

However I tend to believe that it's used since it simply converts the String by simply calling new BigDecimal(strValue), which actually works for a string like "12.45"

So, I speculate, that behind the scenes, there are actually two converters, one which will convert String to BigDecimal by simply calling new BigDecimal(strValue) which will work for Strings with a delimiter of ".", and one which uses my annotated NumberFormat, which uses the default locale delimiter of ",".

Can anyone confirm the above or correct me where I am wrong?

Comment: What is the default locale used by the JVM?

Comment: running Locale.getDefault() gets me "de_DE". Does this answer your question?